# how does the performance gets increased when I use large size files using socket programming in c

Tags: c, sockets

I have a code(TCP socket programming in c) which sends the files to the target system from source system.I have done a test with 10 files of 8KB size each and another test with 10 files of 8 MB size each .Throughput for 8MB block files is more when compared to 8KB files.Throughput is getting increased linearly for small to large size files.

Can someone please explain how does the performcae gets changed whether we send small size file or large size file using socket programming.

Note: I am using sendfile()(without using TCP_CORK and TCP_NODELAY options)

Comment: If you're just looking at throghput, you'll be opening/closing the files less frequently, hence there's fewer syscalls made and you spend more time actually sending the files. Moreover, if you're naively sending the data (i.e. calling `send` with a size of 8MB), then the `send` call will again use fewer syscalls and spend longer in kernel-land.

Comment: yes I agree but I have repeated the test several times gave me the same reslut..and the throughput ,(MBS MB per seocnd) is linearly getting increased whether I use send and write () calls or Sendfile() ..how does it matters whether it is small file or large in the performance

Comment: Show your code. There are various possible explanations but it starts with a post of the code you are talking about.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you open a new connection for each file, I think that the difference in throughput that you observe may be caused by:

- Syscalls time: open file, open connection, sendfile etc. Their number depend on the number of files, so if you have big files their impact will be reduced.
- Connections time: TCP connections take time to open (because of the three way handshake, that requires at least a round trip time) and they take time to reach their full speed (look at the [slow start algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slow-start) for an example).

So, there are some fixed amounts of time that you have to wait independently of the amount of data that you are going to send and that will impact more if you send less data.

I guess that in normal situations, opening connections slows way more than the increased number of syscalls. Some ways to speed up your program would be to open connections in parallel or multiplex the file data into a single, long running connection.

Comment: Why more syscalls or connections? In both cases the OP send 10 files, that is 10 times open, socket, connect, accept, read, sendfile, close and close.

Comment: You are right. Anyway i better explain what i mean when i say that their impact in proportion is lower for bigger files.

Comment: @alk You are amortizing the connect handshake cost over a longer transfer.

Comment: I think the main reason is the slow start mechanism of TCP. Anyway +1